# Making a CharField use a PasswordInput in the admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a Django site in which the site admin inputs their Twitter Username/Password in order to use the Twitter API.  The Model is set up like this:

```
class TwitterUser(models.Model):
screen_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.screen_name
```

I need the Admin site to display the `password` field as a password input, but can't seem to figure out how to do it.   I have tried using a `ModelAdmin` class, a `ModelAdmin` with a `ModelForm`, but can't seem to figure out how to make django display that form as a password input...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets), you can build your own form, something like this:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, PasswordInput

class TwitterUserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TwitterUser
        widgets = {
            'password': PasswordInput(),
        }
```

Or you can do it [like this](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/57053067ce402221/dfc68284c91fd5ae):

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, PasswordInput

class TwitterUserForm(ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput())
    class Meta:
        model = TwitterUser
```

I've no idea which one is better - I slightly prefer the first one, since it means you'll still get any `help_text` and `verbose_name` from your model.

Regardless of which of those two approaches you take, you can then make the admin use your form like this (in your app's `admin.py`):

```
from django.contrib import admin

class TwitterUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = TwitterUserForm

admin.site.register(TwitterUser, TwitterUserAdmin)
```

Comment: I also would say go for the first one, I am not sure if the clean method for password will be the same in the second version.

Comment: Thanks, I did see this in the docs but forgot to add the `, TwitterUserAdmin` to the `admin.site.register` line, so it obviously wasn't working right.  Thanks!

Comment: I get "This field is required" when I try to edit the object without changing the password.